# How to display the body of the spreadsheet document?

Tags: html, google-sheets

So there is some landing page, where link, that opens document in blank page. But it opens with all toolbars and other stuff. The main aim, to display the document in a new window without all the toolbars, only the body of the document (red border on the picture). Here the picture:

[image]

How to realize this? With API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open a Google Drive spreadsheet, the URL has "/edit" at the end. If you change this to "/preview" then you will get a view-only version of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Nice. That's what I need. However, the filters in this mode will not work?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately not. Filters are an interactive thing and preview mode isn't.